# How to filter a list only by name - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I need to implement a search filter, just by name. I am not good with angularjs so I could use some help. This is what I did for now, but it needs a bit of tweaking:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search for a pupil..." />

<tr ng-repeat="student in studentData | filter : searchText">
```

just this filter. But in studentData, i should search through studentData.FullName only. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can specify the property you want to filter by like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentData | filter : {fullName: searchText}">
```

However, keep in mind that this will be an exact text match, including casing "Joe" is not equal to "joe".

The above will work, but IMO it's not the **best** solution.  Below is my recommendation

Change the HTML to point at a new array of data:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search for a pupil..." />
<tr ng-repeat="student in filteredStudentData">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.searchText = ''; //start as an empty string
$scope.studentData = [ ... ]; //your real data goes in here
$scope.filteredStudentData = []; // start as an empty array

//Watch the `searchText` property for changes
$scope.$watch('searchText ', function(newValue, oldValue){
  //remove whitespace, and make it all lowercase - note the `.trim()` only works on IE 9+
  var normalizedSearchText = (newValue || '').toLowerCase().trim();

  //Now only include the relevant results in the `filteredStudentData` array
  //note that the `.filter()` method is only available on IE9+
  $scope.filteredStudentData = $scope.studentData.filter(function (student) {
    return 
       normalizedSearchText === student.fullName.toLowerCase().trim() ||
       normalizedSearchText === student.someOtherProperty.toLowerCase().trim() ||
       normalizedSearchText === student.anotherExampleProperty.toLowerCase().trim();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, thats what I tried to do from the start, trim/lowercase/new array, but this works perfectly, the simpler one, no problems with caps. But cool response, i will keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search for a pupil..." />

<tr ng-repeat="student in studentData | filter :{name:searchText}:true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search for a pupil..." />

<tr ng-repeat="student in studentData | filter:{student.Fullname:searchText}">
```